# Android Layout, move window

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

Maybe you remember the draggable window in android donut. You have something like a tab. If you tap on this tab with your finger a window slides up an reveals all the applications that are installed on your android phone.

Has anyone an idea how to realize this in a layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am looking for this...[SlidingDrawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html)